# how to replace XML values with values from a list

Tags: python, xml, list, indexing

I am trying to update start times in an XML file with new start times from a list in python. This is a sample of the XML (There are 9 orders in the list)

```
    <ppr:Group name="Order lists">
        <ppr:ProductionProgram ppr:id="1">
         <ppr:name>firmOrders</ppr:name>
         <ppr:Order ppr:id="1|19077013">
            <ppr:number>M742019552</ppr:number>
            <ppr:startTime>2019-10-28T06:45:00</ppr:startTime>
            <ppr:property name="Line code" value="G" metadata="true" />
            <ppr:modelRef refBy="pprId">M1|19077013</ppr:modelRef>
         </ppr:Order>
```

I have a list of the new start times

```
    newtimes = ['2020-03-16T08:00:02', '2020-03-16T08:00:03'] ect...
```

I know how to get to the xml start time values using,

```
    for x in productionprogram.iter('{http://ManHub.PPRData}startTime'):
        x.text =
```

just not sure what to set it = to... something that replaces the values with 'newtimes' in order

Thanks!

Comment: You seem really close to a solution yourself already. Have you read the section in the documentation called ["Modifying an XML file"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)? If so, is there something more specific you're stuck on? You might also want to check up [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: yes! I have been using that, I feel confident in the XML part, just not sure how to step through the list.. my thoughts are to start with index 0 and move up 1 with each iteration of the list, just not sure how to accomplish that

Comment: For a [mcve], please post a fuller XML sample that includes root or wherever the `xmlns` namespaces are defined since prefixes are used. And a more complete Python code block with `import` lines and not isolated snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't so much about how to "replace XML values" then it's about how to "keep track" of how many times you've iterated inside of a loop.

What you want is [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Let's try it out with a simple example.

I have a file containing the days of the weeks and their names called **week.xml**:

```
<week>
    <day>
        <name>Monday</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>Tuesday</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>Wednesday</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>Thursday</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>Friday</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>Saturday</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>Sunday</name>
    </day>
</week>
```

Let's replace their names using a list of values:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('week.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

short_days = ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN']
for idx, day in enumerate(root.findall("day")):
    day.find("name").text = short_days[idx]

tree.write("short_week.xml")
```

And here is the new file called **short_week.xml**:

```
<week>
    <day>
        <name>MON</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>TUE</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>WED</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>THU</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>FRI</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>SAT</name>
    </day>
    <day>
        <name>SUN</name>
    </day>
</week>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to modify a bit and use 'iter' instead of 'findall' because the times aren't direct children of the root so it ended up looking like this